# The project 'projectname.Shared' cannot be added to the solution because it is already a member of the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, shared-project

Topic: Adding a shared (universal) library project to a DirectX+XAML Universal App in Visual Studio 2013

I have created a VS2013 Direct-X/XAML Universal App. Since it's a universal
app, there are 3 projects:

- a project for Win 8.1
- a project for Win Phone 8.1
- a "shared node" for code which is shared between the Win 8.1 and Win Phone 8.1 project.

I have also created a VS2013 Static Library (for Universal Apps). Since it's a library for
universal apps, it contains:

- a project for Win 8.1
- a project for Win Phone 8.1
- a "shared node" for code which is shared between the Win 8.1 and Win Phone 8.1 project.

I would like to add the static library project(s) to the Direct-X/XAML app *AND* be able to
see the shared library source code.

Since the static library contains 2 projects,
I have to add both projects to the application. I also update the dependency list so that the Win 8.1 project in the app 
is dependent on the Win 8.1 lib project and the Win Phone 8.1 app project is dependent on the Win Phone 8.1 lib project.

After I'm done with the above, I don't see the shared node from the library. I would like to be able to see the source
code which is shared between the library projects.

How do I solve this problem?

[image: Visual Description of the problem]

[image: Adding shared items]